# Fixed points of tanh function (pitchfork bifurcation)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, hyperbolic-functions

I'm trying to work out a bifurcation diagram for the function given by

$x'=x+\tanh(rx) $

for all values of $r$.

I know that $x_*=0$ is a fixed point for all values of $r$. I can verify graphically that two more fixed points will appear for values of $r<-1$, however I am unable to explain quantitatively why this is so. Playing around with graphs makes me believe that as $r$ gets smaller and smaller (approaches $-\infty$, the new fixed points $x_*$ approach $\pm1$.

Can someone please give me an explanation as to why this is the case? I don't have much (any) experience with hyperbolic functions, so perhaps something is escaping me here. It does not seem as though there is an easy way to explicitly solve for $x_*$ in terms of $r$.

Comment: Note that struggling to find [the right symbols](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) aren't necessary.  We've got everything from \infty, and \pm, to $\color{red}{\heartsuit}$ (\color{red}{\heartsuit}).

Comment: Do you know the definition of the hyperbolic tan? $$\tanh(x)=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}$$

Comment: I am aware that that is the definition. I do not, however, understand how to apply it to this question.

Comment: Have you tried the following limit?  For it to be a fixed point, you are looking for $x'=0$?: $$\lim_{r\to-\infty}\tanh(rx)?\color{white}{\text{ the limit approaches $\pm1$ depending on the sign of $x$.}}$$ (There is hidden text to the right of the limit if you are confused.  Highlight it to reveal)

Comment: Oops, maybe not that $x'=0$, but some reasoning can be done.  What are you fix-point iterating anyways?  (putting in an example value would be very helpful for understanding the question)

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking you mean to calculate the following:

$$x_{n+1}=x_n+\tanh(rx_n)$$

And you have clearly seen that $x_*=0$ is a fixed point for all $r$ since

$$0=0+\tanh(0)$$

---

If you take the limit $r\to-\infty$, the problem changes to the following:

$$x_{n+1}=\begin{cases}x_n+1&;x_n<0\\x_n-1&;x_n>0\\x_n&;x_n=0\end{cases}$$

So, $x_*=\pm1$ are not actually fixed points in this scenario.  For example:

$$x_k=0.5$$

$$x_{k+1}=-0.5$$

$$x_{k+2}=0.5$$

And so on, the values will alternate around $0$, and if $a_0$ was an integer, it would converge to $0$.

---

Lastly, the problem is to find the following solution:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=L$$

Assuming the limit exists, we are tasked with solving

$$L=L+\tanh(rL)$$

$$0=\tanh(rL)$$

$$L=\frac{\operatorname{arctanh}(0)}r$$

which has the single real solution

$$L=0$$

Thus, $a_*=0$ is the only fixed point.